# SQL: How do I delete rows that are also in another table?

Tags: sql, teradata, anti-join

Say I have two tables. E.g,

Table 1:

```
Store Product 
 1       2    
 1       1
 2       3
 2       4
```

And Table 2

```
Store Product 
 1       2    
 2       3
```

How do I delete all the rows in Table 1 that are also in Table 2?

So, new Table 1 would be:

```
Store Product 
 1       1
 2       4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem want :

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.store = t.store and 
                        t2.product = t1.product
                 );
```

Similarly delete version would be :

```
delete 
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1 
              from table2 t2 
              where t2.store = t.store and 
                    t2.product = t1.product
             );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
DELETE
    t1
FROM
    table1 t1
WHERE
    (t1.store, t1.product) IN ( SELECT 
                                     t2.store, 
                                     t2.product 
                                from 
                                    table2 t2);
```

Comment: This will delete too many rows. e.g. `1  3`. Should be a *non-correlated multi-column subquery* instead: ` WHERE (store, product) IN (
                    SELECT 
                        store, product from table2)`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @dnoeth, I updated my query with non-correlated multi-column subquery.